# How to handle exception from underlying dataset of an Ultrawingrid (winforms)

Tags: winforms, ultrawingrid

I have an UltraWinGrid with a dataset behind it.  In the datatable's Row_Changing event handler, I do some checking of the data and throw an exception if it is invalid.  I want to display a message for this exception within my application.  However, the UltraGrid seems to catch the exception and display it's own message box with the exception.  How can I prevent the message box from being displayed, and catch that error within my application?

```
private static void Row_Changing( object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e )
{
    if( <some logic to test the row values>)
        throw new Exception("you can't do that");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked it out, but I thought I'd create this question anyway (since I have already typed it out).

You need to handle the Error event of the UltraGrid and set e.Cancel to true to prevent the dialog box from popping up:

```
public Form1()
{
    ...

    this.ultraGrid1.Error += new Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ErrorEventHandler(ultraGrid1_Error);
}

void ultraGrid1_Error(object sender, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ErrorEventArgs e)
{
    //< deal with the error here>
    // set Cancel to true to prevent the dialog box from showing.
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```